# Expected Syntax error while writing groovy code

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, continuous-deployment, cicd, groovyshell

I am facing syntax error while deploying tomcat on ubuntu server using shared library.

Shared library code is

```
def newDeploy(ip,contextPath)
{
  sh "deploy adapters: [tomcat9(credentialsId: '2d7bffd1-b890-4532-a303-e2f1dcf6d44a', path: '', url: ${ip})], contextPath: ${contextPath}, war: '**/*.war'"
}
```

In jenkins pipeline code is

```
stage('ContDeploy')
    {
        steps
        {
            script
            {
                cicd.newDeploy("172.31.25.99:8080","testap")
            }
        }
    }
```

how to write groovy code to pass token key to authorize tomcat to be installed on ubuntu server?

I tried using 3 colons(''') at the end and start of the code but not worked. Double colon also not worked. space also not worked nor dash(-) worked in between tomcat and credentialsId.

Comment: I assumed those are all meant to be tomcat, not tomecat...

Comment: Yes, Its just a typo error. Sorry about that.